# FancyBox Open overlay

Tags: javascript, fancybox-2

I want to open the overlay of fancybox manually (without content, just overlay and the loading picture).

```
$.fancybox.showLoading();
$.fancybox.helpers.overlay.open({closeClick : false});
```

The "loading" image show up but overlay.open do nothing.

Comment: As long as i know to display the overlay you need to use overlayShow

Comment: Do you have an example code ?